# Any freeware like Piky Basket?

Tags: file-transfer

[Piky Basket](http://www.conceptworld.com/Piky/piky_pictour_1.asp) is one tool that allows you to copy files from various sources and paste them to a single destination. Are there any such freeware tools that do the same functionality and adds itself to the windows right-click menu?

Comment: I've used TeraCopy and BurstCopy, but they are not exactly the same as Piky Basket. Still, you can do the same thing with them without using a basket. They use queuing logic.

Comment: Why you are not using Piky Basket itself? The new version is even 64 bit compatible.

Comment: It ain't a freeware anymore!

Comment: Interesting to see that the mods haven't closed this as 'subjective'. Heaven forbid there might be more than one 'right' answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have a look at FileBucket](http://skwire.dcmembers.com/wb/pages/software/file-bucket.php) (freeware)

[image]

Comment: Care to explain what it does @chukked?